# kendo multiselect option attribute set

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying Kendo multiselect demo.

```
var multi = $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

In them I want to set `option` element `attribute` `selected` if `value = "2"`.
like `$('option[value=2]').attr('selected','selected');`
Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

add an databound event to multiselect

```
function MultiSelectDataBound()
{
  var multiSelect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect"),
  multiSelect.dataSource.filter({}); //clear applied filter before setting value
  multiSelect.value(2);
}
```

Or you can create a text box and button add an clicked event and get values from text box

```
function btnClicked()
{ 
   var multiSelect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect"),
   multiSelect.value($("#textbox").val().split(","));
}
```

[For more information abot MultiSelect](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/multiselect/api.html)